# How to remove/disable Customize list and setting from ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have a list where Customize list and setting should only be accessible to myself. There are people who has editable/contribute access to this list.I want them to work on all but these two sections.

[image]

how do i remove or disable these sections from ribbon ?

Comment: I found a way to disable it via css. Please see this link http://bistesh.blogspot.ae/. is there any way to disable it using permissions or other settings  ? even for those who has editable access

Comment: what you need to do is create a new permission level and remove design rights. That should work